# Is it possible to authenticate server to server with Google Calendar API?

Tags: oauth, calendar, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

So I read the following on the [Authorizing Requests to the Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth) page written by Google folks.

> Your application must use OAuth 2.0 to authorize requests. No other authorization protocols are supported. If your application uses Google Sign-In, some aspects of authorization are handled for you.

My knowledge of OAuth 2.0 is limited so I'm not sure if that means that I cannot get a one-time auth token for a user?

I'm building an app that will need to CRUD events for a user in the background based on other stuff. So I can't have the user authenticate over and over again. Is there a way around here?

If not, is there an Google Calendar alternative that has a dependable API that I could use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user authenticates your application you are given an Access token (good for one hour) and a refresh token.    You should save the refresh token,  when ever you need to access the users data you can take the refresh token and ask Google to give you a new access token.   It is the access token which gives you access to there account.

I wrote a tutorial that tries to explain Oauth2 how to set it up and how it works.   [Google Developer console Oauth2](http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/)

Comment: Yea thats why I thought also. Quick follow up question though - I know that when I get an access_token I also get a expire time along with it. So if I want a new access_token from a refresh_token, do I have to do it before the expire time or can I use it whenever? Because if I have to do it before the expire time then I'll have to write a job that renews the refresh token before every hour.

Comment: You can request a new one every time you want to access the api if you like however it may be a few seconds slower due to the request to the server. Probably not very polite either but the server doesn't care spam away. No need to wait for it to expire